# User root as default in terminal ubuntu 11.10

Tags: root

I have installed ubuntu 11.10 on vmware workstation 7. When i login to ubuntu and open terminal, by default it is coming as root. But during installation i have given steve as username.

If i give pwd it is showing /home/steve. But still terminal shows root@ubuntu-#.

I am new to linux. How to fix this?

Comment: What does the command whoami say?

Comment: whoami gives steve

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the output of *whoami* is *steve* means you are **not** logged in as root, but as steve. Then *root@ubuntu-°* is just your prompt. You can change it by means of the following command:

```
 PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$"
```

You must copy it exactly as it is, better copy and paste it.